# how can I change the values of x and y axis independently with each car?

Tags: python

how can i change the values of the xAxis and the yAxis because what I'm having as an output are only zeroes.

```
#I want to have a result like this:
    Car: Red       xAxis: 10 yAxis: 50
    Car: Yellow    xAxis: 20 yAxis: 40
    Car: Green     xAxis: 30 yAxis: 30
    Car: Blue      xAxis: 40 yAxis: 20
    Car: White     xAxis: 50 yAxis: 10

class Car():
    def __init__(self,color):
        self.color = color
        self.xAxis = 0
        self.yAxis = 0
    def moveUp(self):
        self.yAxis+=1
    def moveRight(self):
        self.xAxis+=1

CarColor = ['Red','Yellow','Green','Blue','White']
CarList = []
for eachColor in CarColor:
CarList.append(Car(eachColor))
for eachCar in CarList:
    print("Car:",eachCar.color,end=' ') 
    print("xAxis:",eachCar.xAxis,end=' ') 
    print("yAxis:",eachCar.yAxis,end='\n')
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'changing X and Y independently'? You mean you want to increment X and Y by 1 when you add a new car ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I get your question correctly.

from what I understand and to get a similar result for the one you wrote, you need to use the methods `moveUp()` and `moveRight()` on your Car instance to cause the change you want, an example to get your sample output would be like this:

```
red_car = Car('Red')
for i in range(50):
    red_car.moveUp()
for j in range(10):
    red_car.moveRight()

print("Car:",red_car.color,end=' ') 
print("xAxis:",red_car.xAxis,end=' ') 
print("yAxis:",red_car.yAxis,end='\n')
```

Also it's not recommended to use CamelCase for naming your variables, I recommend you check python's [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Comment: I added the output that I want above. I've used the method that you suggested but it makes the code way longer that's why I'm trying to use a loop so that it will be shorter I guess. I'm very new to programming so please bare with me hahahaha

Comment: since you want to have different values for each car, you are bounded for having to use both the ```moveUp()``` and ```moveRight()``` functions on each car, to make the code less bulky, I would initialize another list and store the wanted x and y values for each car in a tuple as a single element in the list, then you can make only 2 for loops just after the initialization of the car instance to reach the x and y values for all cars.